# Omxplayer change volume when playing

Tags: streaming, omxplayer, radio

I am trying to change volume. OMXPlayer is not using ALSA so it is not reacting.
I am playing live radio stream and I want to change volume of it without stopping the radio.
Is this possible? If yes, how?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am not a PHP expert but I think you start the omx with a function like `proc_open` inside your PHP code.

If you send `+` and `-` characters to STDIN pipe gathered from proc_open call, you can control the omx sound.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `+` and `-` keys on the keyboard, while the terminal is focused.

Since you're not able to focus the terminal, you'll need to create a script that handles all the input for OMXPlayer.

Details and how it was done in PHP can be found here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=7987

Basically the concept is to create a script with runs in a loop polling a file or pipe for new data.

When new data is found, it consumes that data and executes commands to control omxplayer.

The file is written to by php code with a web page front end.

You can accomplish the controlling script by using a method similar to this github:
https://github.com/KenT2/pyomxplayer/blob/master/omxchild.sh

Comment: I know about this feature, but my terminal is not focused. It's done remotely via PHP